# Изменить название кнопки в с#

Tags: c#, winforms, access

Создала базу данных  в аксес , подключила к DataGridBView , как при выборе ячейки изменить название кнопки с (Добавить ) на (Изменить)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно запрограммировать обработчик события CellEnter или CellContentClick объекта DataGridView и в нём менять текст кнопки.